# How to use wpd_Api to copy file to a folder location in device

Tags: android, mtp, wpd

I want to copy files from my pc to my android device using WPD-Api.

I am able to copy to root folder but i am not able to copy to folder inside root.

I tried to enumerate content in device but that also not working.
I tried using [link](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CBwQFjAAahUKEwiXpsOrqfTIAhXDJ5QKHWE1CKE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcgeers.wordpress.com%2F2012%2F04%2F17%2Fwpd-transfer-content-to-a-device%2F&usg=AFQjCNGCAo1qqQ04E_CGS31COzIiTJCzdQ&sig2=AFQyTyOslHx3kZjbiLJBYw&bvm=bv.106379543,d.dGo) but was not useful. I am sharing my code snippet also

```
foreach (var device in deviceCollection)
            {
                try
                {
                    device.Connect();

                    var root = device.GetContents();
                    int i = 0;
                    PortableDeviceFolder sdCardRootFolder = null;
                    PortableDeviceFolder DCIM = null;
                    foreach (var deviceObject in root.Files)
                    {
                        i++;
                        if (deviceObject is PortableDeviceFolder)
                        {
                            sdCardRootFolder = deviceObject as PortableDeviceFolder;


                        }
                    }

                    if (sdCardRootFolder != null)
                    {
                        device.EnumerateContents(sdCardRootFolder);

                        foreach (var deviceObject in sdCardRootFolder.Files)
                        {
                            if (deviceObject is PortableDeviceFile)
                            {
                                if (deviceObject.Name.StartsWith(DeviceSerial))
                                {
                                    connectToDevice = true;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
```